# Deriving product rule for divergence of a product of scalar and vector function in tensor notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

On page-94 of the 4th edition in the international version of Griffith's Electrodynamic, the following identity is used:

$$ \int \left[ V(\nabla \cdot \vec{E} ) + \vec{E} \cdot \nabla V \right]dV= \oint V \vec{E} \cdot dA$$

Where, $ \vec{E}$ is a vector function and $V$ is a scalar function.

My goal is to prove the above identity using tensor calculus notation.

---

The equation reminded me a bit of how the covariant derivative acted in Tensor calculus, so I tried that:

$$ \nabla_i (VE^i) = E^i \nabla_i (V) + V \nabla_i (E^i) \tag{1}$$

This equation in vector in vector notation is:

$$ \nabla \cdot( VE) = \text{?}+ V \nabla \cdot \vec{E}$$

Now, I can't figure out how to get the dot product in the $E^i \nabla_i (V)$ term

---

[Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954158/proof-of-the-product-rule-for-the-divergence): Has the worked out proof of the above identity, but I can't seem to figure how to simplify equation (2) from it

Comment: The thing in square brackets is $\text{div}(V\,\vec{E})$. So, apply the divergence theorem. WHat you wrote as $\vec{E}\nabla V$ in the last line is wrong, it should just be $\vec{E}\cdot \nabla V$ (the standard inner product of $\vec{E}$ with $\nabla V$).

Comment: Far as I understand the left side of equal is a scalar while the right side is a vector. Are you sure the formula is right?

Comment: Oh right, but how did you translate $E^i \nabla_i (V) $ into $ \vec{E} \cdot \nabla V$, I don't see the contraction for divergence

Comment: can you write out the definition of $E^i$, $\nabla_iV$ and of the standard inner product on the LHS? btw the proof of this vector identity is given in Griffiths (see the product rule section in the beginning)

Comment: Hm so $\nabla_i V=- Z^{ik} E^i e_k$, I am not sure what you mean by the definition of $E^i$ .. I guess I would define it as the component of $E$ w.r.t some basis. I don't see a contraction with the covariant metric tensor here for a dot product

Comment: you're getting your formulas all mixed up (toooooo many mismatched indices). Also, what is $Z$? I suggest you keep it simple and take a look at the proof already provided in Griffiths; this is really a simple consequence of the (very simple) definition of divergence in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (or $\Bbb{R}^n$) and the usual product rule.

Comment: I had checked the book and found the correct derivation as you said, but I am trying to figure out how to fix my derivation to be correct as well. $Z^{ik}$ is the contravariant metric tensor defined by the action $Z^{ik} e_k = e^i$. I wrote it because $ \nabla_i V = \frac{\partial V}{\partial Z^i} e^i$ where $e^i$ is the contravariant basis

Comment: I'm assuming $Z$ is the metric (instead of the more traditional $g$?)

Comment: Yes here I have contravariant metric tensor @K.defaoite

Answer (score 2):

Seems you're getting tangled up in notation. Your integrand, in a Euclidean frame at least and with and a slight change of notation, is
\begin{equation*}
\sum_i\ \biggl( v \frac{\partial E^i}{\partial x^i} + E^i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x^i} \biggr).
\end{equation*}
The term in parentheses is $\partial(v E^i)/\partial x^i$, the divergence of $vE$. Apply the divergence theorem for the integral.

Comment: Okie, this helps but I'm still stuck on how to do write it in a general coordinate system

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured it out. The thing is that the gradient is naturally identified with a convector, hence the product is the dot product, here it is explicitly:

$$ \vec{E} \cdot \nabla V=(E^i e_i) \cdot (\nabla_j V e^j) = E^i \nabla_j V  \delta_i^j= E^i \nabla_i V$$

Hence, the result.

Answer (score 0):

Also in differential forms, where $\tilde{E}$ is the electric field two-form:

$$  \int_{\partial \omega} V \tilde{E}=  \int_{\omega}d (V \tilde{E}) = \int_{ \omega} dV \wedge \tilde{E} + V d \tilde{E} $$

Now, we use the identites:

$$ V d \tilde{E} = V (\nabla \cdot E) dx_1  \wedge dx_2  \wedge dx_3$$

$$ dV \wedge \tilde{E} = -|E|^2 dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3$$

Because $dV = - \star E$. We recover the required.